# How to pass parameters to Rest-Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

Can someone help me in this scenario:

When I invoke this service, `http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/`, I get couple of countries information.

But when I want to get any specific country information like say Finland, I invoke the web service as `http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/Finland` to get the country related info.

To automate the above scenario, how can I parameterize the country name in **Rest-Assured**? I tried below, but doesn't help me.

```
RestAssured.given().
                    parameters("name","Finland").
            when().
                    get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/").
            then().
                body("capital", containsString("Helsinki"));
```

Answer (score 32):

As the documentation explains:

> REST Assured will automatically try to determine which parameter type
> (i.e. query or form parameter) based on the HTTP method. In case of
> GET query parameters will automatically be used and in case of POST
> form parameters will be used.

But in your case it seems you need path parameter instead query parameters.
Note as well that the generic URL for getting a country is `https://restcountries.com/v2/name/{country}`
where `{country}` is the country name.

Then, there are as well multiple ways to transfers path parameters.

Here are few examples

Example using pathParam():

```
// Here the key name 'country' must match the url parameter {country}
RestAssured.given()
        .pathParam("country", "Finland")
        .when()
            .get("https://restcountries.com/v2/name/{country}")
        .then()
            .body("capital", containsString("Helsinki"));
```

Example using variable:

```
String cty = "Finland";

// Here the name of the variable (`cty`) have no relation with the URL parameter {country}
RestAssured.given()
        .when()
            .get("https://restcountries.com/v2/name/{country}", cty)
        .then()
            .body("capital", containsString("Helsinki"));
```

Now if you need to call different services, you can also parametrize the "service" like this:

```
// Search by name
String val = "Finland";
String svc = "name";

RestAssured.given()
        .when()
            .get("https://restcountries.com/v2/{service}/{value}", svc, val)
        .then()
            .body("capital", containsString("Helsinki"));


// Search by ISO code (alpha)
val = "CH"
svc = "alpha"

RestAssured.given()
        .when()
            .get("https://restcountries.com/v2/{service}/{value}", svc, val)
        .then()
            .body("capital", containsString("Bern"));

// Search by phone intl code (callingcode)
val = "359"
svc = "callingcode"

RestAssured.given()
        .when()
            .get("https://restcountries.com/v2/{service}/{value}", svc, val)
        .then()
            .body("capital", containsString("Sofia"));
```

After you can also easily use the JUnit `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` to feed the parameters 'svc' and 'value' for a unit test.

Comment: This is such an elegant way of parameterizing path values! Just as stated by the RequestSpecification API, this approach does indeed improve readability and allows path reuse! 
http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/1.2.3/com/jayway/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#pathParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the GET call incorrectly.

The `parameters("name","Finland")` will be converted only as **query** parameter or **form** parameter for **GET** and **POST/PUT** respectively

```
RestAssured.when().
                    get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/Finland").
            then().
                body("capital", containsString("Helsinki"));
```

is the only way to do. Since it's a java DSL, you can construct the URL all by yourself and pass it to get() if required

If the URL with a GET request had to fetch the same details been like :

http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1?name=Finland,

The your DSL would be something like:

```
RestAssured.given().parameters("name","Finland").
                when().
                        get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1")
```

When you have a GET request, your parameters transform into `queryParameters`.

More info from this link:
https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Parameters

Comment: It seems, ur Web service call is not correct, when i invoke, http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1?name=Finland, i am getting information of all countries, rather if you try "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/Finland" you are getting specific country information.

Comment: If we pass parameter by value, then what is the advantage of having parameters here?  String strCountryName="Finland";
  RestAssured.given().
//       parameters("name","Finland").
     when().
       get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/"+strCountryName).
     then().
      body("capital", hasItem("Helsinki")); Why do i need parameter above which i commented?

Comment: In that case you wont need parameters() at all. Its the other option for you to do. parameters are only for GET's query param and POST/PUTs form parameters. Not for path parameters if you get what i mean.

Comment: Karthik, can you bit elaborate. It can be great with example.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a request cpecification (say in a `@Before`) first:

```
RequestSpecification requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
    .setBaseUri (BASE_URL)
    .setBasePath (BASE_PATH)
    .addPathParam(
        "pathParamName", "pathParamValue",
        "anotherPathParamName", "anotherPathParamValue")
    .addQueryParam(
        "queryparamName", "queryParamValue",
        "anotherQueryParamName", "anotherQueryParamValue")
    .setAuth(basic(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
    .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .setAccept(ContentType.JSON)
    .log(LogDetail.ALL)
    .build();
```

and then reuse it multiple times as follows:

```
given()
    .spec(requestSpecification)
    .get("someResource/{pathParamName}/{anotherPathParamName}")
.then()
    .statusCode(200);
```

You can rebuild the request specification wherever you want. And if some changes will happen you can easily change your params names in one place.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpUrl url1 = HttpUrl.parse("https:google.com").newBuilder()
                       .addQueryParameter("search","parameter")
                       .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely user pathParam(String arg0, Object arg1) for achieving parameterization. Use the below example, if you using @DataProvider for providing the data.

By this you can provide multiple data using the DataProvider and also can also use APache POI for getting data from Excel Sheet.

```
@DataProvider(name="countryDataProvider")
    public String[][] getCountryData(){     
        String countryData[][] = {{"Finland"}, {"India"}, {"Greenland"}};
        return (countryData);
    }
@Test(dataProvider="countryDataProvider")
    public void getCountryDetails(String countryName){
        given().
        pathParam("country", countryName).
        when().
        get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/{country}").
        then().
        assertThat().
        .body("capital", containsString("Helsinki"));
    }
```

Comment: What will happens in the second iteration of your test? I think you should also add the expectations in the DataProvider.

Answer (score -2):

parameters method is deprecated and start using params.

Eg: `RestAssured.given().params("name","Finland")`

Comment: Yes, but this is still convert the param as Query Parameter which in that case is not what the API wants. For path parameter you have to use `pathParam(..)` instead.
Note also the right name is `param` and not `params`